# open_sharded_output_tfrecords causes FailedPreconditionError Writer is not open

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to implement the Tensorflow Detection API following mainly the tutorial and I am running into an issue when trying to generate the **TFRecord**.

I have gotten to a point where I generate the tfexamples and want to write them to a list of tfrecord files. I have seen a [couple examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/124694/object_detection.dataset_tools.tf_record_creation_util.open_sharded_output_tfrecords) using the [open_sharded_output_tfrecords](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/tf_record_creation_util.py) function like this:

```
with contextlib2.ExitStack() as tf_record_close_stack:
    output_records = tf_record_creation_util.open_sharded_output_tfrecords(
        tf_record_close_stack, FLAGS.output_file, FLAGS.num_shards)
```

This returns a list of TFRecords writers which can later be used like this:

```
output_records[shard_index].write(tf_example)
```

where `shard_index` is an integer and `tf_example` is the tfexample.

When I try to implement it I get an error (see full report on the bottom).

> FailedPreconditionError: Writer is closed.

It creates the files:
[image]

Any idea or hint what I might be doing wrong with open_sharded_output_tfrecords and how to correct it?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

This is my code:

```
def convert_to_tfrecord_error(df,output_folder,num_shards):
    import contextlib2

    from object_detection.dataset_tools import tf_record_creation_util

    #Step 1: Initialize utils for sharded 
    with contextlib2.ExitStack() as tf_record_close_stack:
        output_tfrecords = tf_record_creation_util.open_sharded_output_tfrecords(
            tf_record_close_stack, output_folder_test, num_shards)
        



    image_nr = 0


    #Step 2: Write record to shard
    for index,_ in df.iterrows():


        #generate the example
        tf_example = generate_tf_example(df,index)

        #get the shard
        shard_index = image_nr % num_shards

        #write to shard
        output_tfrecords[shard_index].write(tf_example)

        #update image number
        image_nr = image_nr +1

        #notify after 100 images
        if image_nr%100 == 0: 
            print(f"{image_nr} images written")
```

Full report:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling `output_tfrecords[shard_index].close()` after writing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the writer has exited after the `with` statement finishes:

```
with contextlib2.ExitStack() as tf_record_close_stack:
        output_tfrecords = tf_record_creation_util.open_sharded_output_tfrecords(
            tf_record_close_stack, output_folder_test, num_shards)
```

This makes the insertions outside of the `tf_record_close_stack` constraint. Therefore, just keep those following codes inside the `with` statement or you have to replace `with contextlib2.ExitStack()` as a `tf_record_close_stack = contextlib2.ExitStack()` variable and close it after finishing the `for` loop by  `tf_record_close_stack.close()`.